# Syncfusion Dialog Rename option does not work

Tags: asp.net, webforms, syncfusion

```
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="scritPANEID" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" SupportsPartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <div class="control">
                <ej:Dialog ID="RenameForm" Title="Rename" Containment=".control" EnableModal="true" ShowOnInit="false" Height="200px" Width="400px" runat="server">
                    <Position XValue="350px" YValue="350px" />
                    <DialogContent>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Rename
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="RenameForm_TxtBx_Update" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="RenameForm_TxtBx" CssClass="ejinputtext" style="width: 100%"> </asp:TextBox>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <br />
                                    <ej:Button ID="renameBtn" Text="Rename" CssClass="e-btn" Width="100px" Height="30px" runat="server" Size="Medium" Type="Button" ClientSideOnClick="renameok_click"></ej:Button>
                                    <ej:Button ID="cancelBtn" Text="Cancel" CssClass="e-btn" Width="100px" Height="30px" runat="server" Size="Medium" Type="Button" ClientSideOnClick="rename_closeclick"></ej:Button>
                                    <label id="Renameerrorlbl" class="error" for="btn"></label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </DialogContent>
                </ej:Dialog>
            </div>
```

Actually I am new to development.
In my working project they use Syncfusion for dialog box.My scenario is  I have dropdown(asp.net dropdown) that have some names. if i change that name it set perfectly. Then i rename that it doesn't work what i have do.

Actually I try to add

nothing happend. Thanks in advance.

screenshot link : https://1drv.ms/i/s!AluTfLj5eYIt5IsdPl3OGINsv4Zs9A?e=e8MNW6